# I have an (UK) ordinary degree in mechanical engineering. Is it worth the paper it's printed on?

Tags: job-search

I've had absolutely no luck with job hunting. After months of applications, I've only gotten two interviews (both last year, before the pandemic), and the jobs I got interviews for weren't even vaguely engineering jobs (one was just CAD doodling, the other was basically tier 3 customer service)

I understand most people have honours degrees, so the fact that I can't say I have a 2.1 or whatever is an obvious red flag.

Is there any future down this path? Is this really such a huge red flag for employers that there's nothing I can realisitically do to make myself employable in my field? Is there even a grad programme that would take me so that there's a chance I could get a degree that doesn't seem so worthless?

Comment: This is about the UK job market and has nothing to do with academia.

Comment: At the present time (COVID-19 outbreak), you should feel lucky that you do have job offers, and not just one but two of them.

Comment: @scaaahu I didn't get offered either job, and those were months before COVID hit. I haven't had a call or email from an employer (other than a couple who bothered to let me know I didn't make the cut) this year. I was unclear.

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding. Still, it's normal that you can't find any job at present.. Just stay patient and healthy, wait until the storm passes.

Comment: The problem is, I've been applying for jobs since August last year, long before things fell apart.

Comment: A degree may very well be worth the paper it's printed on (i.e id led to a lot of knowledge) but useless in the job market. In many fields, academic positions are rare and phd degrees useless in Industry. Also many profs see university education not as something that prepares you for industry but to give you a lot of knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're under the impression that fancy degree = job. **That is incorrect**. Fancy degree is nice and all but it's only the first cut. You will need to back your degree up with actual job search skills as well as technical skills.

For the former, this isn't the right Stack Exchange (use [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/)). Read up on all the CV-writing, cover-letter writing, interviewing techniques, etc, that are necessary to get hired. Also be sure to make use of your alma mater's career center, if they have one. They'll have not just job listings, they will usually have counselors who will help polish your CV.

For the latter, I hope you didn't slack off during the degree because there's no substitute for it. If the interviewer asks, "here are two vectors, what is their sum?" you need to be able to answer because if you can't, then the rest of your CV is called into question. Make sure you know the basic coursework, and if you can keep up-to-date with the latest news in the field, even better.

Job searches are not easy. Unfortunately, you'll have to help yourself, because society doesn't owe you a job and nobody else will be able to help you pass the interview. On the other hand, they can be done: after 8 months I'm pretty sure many of your cohort will have found a job, and if they can do it, you can too.

Comment: I think the point is that an "ordinary" degree isn't a fancy degree. Normally degrees in the UK are Honor's degrees, graded 1st class, 2.1 class , 2.2 class, 3rd class. I'd say 95%, of degrees are honors degrees, about 2/3 are 1st or 2.1 .  An ordinary degree is when honors are not awarded. There are several reasons a degree might be "ordinary", but one is that your grades weren't good enought for honors.

Comment: @IanSudbery there are more people in the UK who don't have a degree than there are people who do, so I'd say an ordinary degree is still a fancy degree.

Comment: I'd guess the user is worried that where a degree is a requirement for a job, the recruiter would not treat having an "oridanary" as having a degree.

Answer (score 1):

I sift and interview candidates in a related engineering field. We've started receiving CVs with names and any reference to age (or gender) redacted. This often including university names. Ostensibly this is to reduce unconscious bias, but it does remove much of the relevant information on which to sift. I wouldn't be surprised if we started redacting grades too. They're not always present and I'm not sure I'd spot the difference between a BSc (Hons) and an ordinary degree at sift unless it was spelled out to me clearly as 'third class'. To be honest, we mainly use a degree as a quick filter for academic aptitude. We don't exclude anyone without, but they have to work much harder to evidence from work experience that they meet the bar.

I'm generally recruiting for a pool rather than a role so I'm not often looking for a single best candidate, but a set of people that would add to the team. Ultimately I want to get the best of the set, but it's not quite as dog-eat-dog as only choosing those with first class degrees - experience, demeaner and how well they would fit in have as much to play once you've proved you can attain a degree.

It's a difficult environment right now with COVID-19, but keep at it:

- Apply for jobs at larger firms - they're more likely to be recruiting for more than just the one role. You don't then need to be top-dog, just in the set.
- If you interview well and get offered something that doesn't feel like a perfect fit, take it. It's always easier to find a job when you've already got one - internal opportunities to move sideways or upwards; less pressure to find something quickly. It always looks better on your CV having had a job, than having nothing. If someone has been out of work for some time, I always question 'why?'. You will build up experience whatever you do. Go pick fruit and veg in our farm fields if it comes to it - you'll get a Good Samaritan story to tell at interview if nothing else.
- Ultimately, your degree is worth the paper it's written on, but it's simply a ticket into the game. The knowledge you gained from the degree in your technical specialism, and the knowledge of how to learn is much more valuable. Your 'ticket' in the form of your certificate proves that.
- Make the most of your time while under 'lockdown': tidy up your CV; research companies you want to apply to once the economy kicks back in (I assume many, like us, have paused recruitment for now); volunteer to help other locally (great for a 'personal statement'); take some (free) online courses (e.g. Coursera) to continue to learn and build your skills.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Keep going, Keep going, Keep going...

Some of my friends got jobs within days of graduating, others 18 months later (like me).

Widen your scope, many fields need or use engineers and some surprising opportunities exist, you might find a school will be interested as you have design skills, drawing skills, mathematics skills etc One friend got as job in an insurance company working on evaluating risk - you have to understand the processes and equipment in use to evaluate risk...

So, chin up, all I can say is "tough times" but you **do** have skills.

And I graduated with a degree in engineering so I know the fight.